# xConnect on Azure XP1

Tags: xdb, xconnect

I installed a Vanilla instance of Sitecore 9.0.2 on Azure using xP1 topology. 
All was working as expected, xProfile and xAnalytics pages loading without exceptions. Then I created a publish profile in my solution for that new instance and brought all connection strings to my xml transformation files, to not override the certificate thumbprints. After deploying my VS solution, I opened up the xAnalytics page successfully. Then I imported core, master and web from another instance. I had to create 3 new logins on master db: coreuser, masteruser and webuser. And also created one new user on each database: coreuser in core db, etc. After changing connection strings on CM, CD, Reporting and Processing roles, xAnalytics stopped working. 
A message shows up:

The certificate was not found.

> "message":"An error has occurred.","exceptionMessage":"The certificate
>   was not
>   found.","exceptionType":"System.InvalidOperationException","stackTrace":"
>   at
>   Sitecore.Xdb.Common.Web.Synchronous.SynchronousExtensions.SuspendContextLock[TResult](Func`1
>   taskFactory)\r\n   at
>   Sitecore.ExperienceAnalytics.Core.Repositories.ReferenceData.ReferenceDataSegmentReader.Get(IEnumerable`1
>   keys, NameValueCollection readingPreferences)\r\n   at
>   Sitecore.ExperienceAnalytics.Aggregation.Repositories.AggregationSegmentReader.Get(IEnumerable`1
>   keys, NameValueCollection readingPreferences)\r\n   at
>   Sitecore.ExperienceAnalytics.Api.RequestTypeResolver.GetReportSegments()\r\n
>   at
>   Sitecore.ExperienceAnalytics.Api.RequestTypeResolver.GetRequestType()\r\n
>   at
>   Sitecore.ExperienceAnalytics.Api.Http.ModelBinding.ReportQueryModelBinder.GetModelFromBindingContext(HttpActionContext
>   actionContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)\r\n   at
>   Sitecore.ExperienceAnalytics.Api.Http.ModelBinding.ReportQueryModelBinder.BindModel(HttpActionContext
>   actionContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)\r\n   at
>   System.Web.Http.ModelBinding.ModelBinderParameterBinding.ExecuteBindingAsync(ModelMetadataProvider
>   metadataProvider, HttpActionContext actionContext, CancellationToken
>   cancellationToken)\r\n   at
>   System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpActionBinding.d__0.MoveNext()\r\n---
>   End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown
>   ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n
>   at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)\r\n   at
>   System.Web.Http.Controllers.ActionFilterResult.d__2.MoveNext()\r\n---
>   End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown
>   ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n
>   at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)\r\n   at
>   System.Web.Http.Filters.AuthorizationFilterAttribute.d__2.MoveNext()\r\n---
>   End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown
>   ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n
>   at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)\r\n   at
>   System.Web.Http.Filters.AuthorizationFilterAttribute.d__2.MoveNext()\r\n---
>   End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown
>   ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n
>   at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)\r\n   at
>   System.Web.Http.Filters.AuthorizationFilterAttribute.d__2.MoveNext()\r\n---
>   End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown
>   ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n
>   at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)\r\n   at
>   System.Web.Http.Controllers.ExceptionFilterResult.d__0.MoveNext()\r\n---
>   End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown
>   ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n
>   at
>   System.Web.Http.Controllers.ExceptionFilterResult.d__0.MoveNext()\r\n---
>   End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown
>   ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n
>   at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)\r\n   at
>   System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.d__1.MoveNext()"

Does anyone know if the certificate is bound somewhere in database level?
Something else I am missing?
I have already double-checked the thumprints in appsettings.config file on xConnect roles and on connectionstrings and on SSL certificates on Azure app services. Looks like something else is causing the issue. 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`xConnect` roles have separate file for `appSettings` where the following setting must be set to `True` when using self-signed certificates: `AllowInvalidClientCertificates`.

We had checked this configuration already. 
The problem was on CM and CD roles. Their `appSettings` section is in the `web.cofing` file and it was set to false. `xAnalytics` page loaded without exceptions after setting AllowInvalidClientCertificates to `True` on CM.

[image]

Thanks to Sitecore support.